# iOS : UINavigation button

Tags: ios6, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

While am trying put navigation button in `UINavigationController` its not showing, But navigation bar is visible! Code is a follows,

```
leftbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
[leftbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(hom) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *random = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftbtn];
rigtbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[rigtbtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
[rigtbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(edity) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[rigtbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *random1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rigtbtn];
navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random;
navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=random1;
```

Whats the wrong in this code?Please help me to solve

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the navigation item of the navigation controller, you have to set the properties of its root view controller (maybe `self` if your code is organized like that). So, if `rootViewController` is a view controller that you init the navigation controller with, you have to write this:

```
rootViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = random;
rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = random1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random;
navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=random1;
```

Use,

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=random;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=random1;
```

You dont have to create or access `UINavigationController` for setting bar button items on navigation bar. If you are pushing the current view controller, then you can use the above code to set these buttons. The pushed view controller already has the properties to set this.